# Property 'attribs' does not exist on type 'Element' [cheerio]

Tags: typescript, cheerio

I am getting the error `Property 'attribs' does not exist on type 'Element'` while running code. I am not sure why it is throwing this error. I checked the type definitions of cheerio and found that `attribs` is the property of `TagElement`. I am not sure how can I fix it as it is automatically picking the type `Element` for `element`. I am new to typescript so maybe I am making a newbie mistake.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.body),
    selection = $('td:nth-child(1) .spaceit_pad'),
    filteredNodes = [];

selection.toArray().map((element) => {
    const attr = element.attribs;
    if (attr.class.split(' ').length === 1) {
        filteredNodes.push(element);
        console.log(typeof element);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a typeguard to check if it is a tagElement you found with your selection:

```
const isTagElement = (element: any): element is cheerio.TagElement => {
  return element?.attribs !== undefined;
};

selection.toArray().map((element: cheerio.Element) => {
  if (isTagElement(element)) {
    const attr = element.attribs;
    if (attr.class.split(" ").length === 1) {
      filteredNodes.push(element);
      console.log(typeof element);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I don't understand, isn't typescript supposed to make our jobs easier?

Comment: Yes but not for small apps. It shows it's value when apps get bigger and you can't keep track of what returns what, what takes what. Then you thank it everyday for being strict with types.

Comment: It's going to get big, atleast in size. So I should thank you for helping me out. :)

Comment: no worries. glad it helped